# rails scaffold with a wrong field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I want to create a scaffold with a model of 2 fields, but I mistakenly added an extra field when I do rails g scaffold. And I rake migrated it. What is the best way to revert the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
rake db:rollback
rails destroy scaffold ScaffoldName
```

and repeat.